# How do I pass configuration options to an Auth0 hosted page using the JS API?

Tags: auth0

I'm using a Hosted Login page on auth0 and the `auth0-js` module to authorize my users.

The docs talk about [a config object](https://auth0.com/docs/hosted-pages/login#the-config-object) and the page itself clearly shows such an object being deserialized.

However, the docs don't remotely talk about how one is supposed to pass this object to the page. Indeed, the docs [indicate an approach](https://auth0.com/docs/hosted-pages/login#customize-text) that doesn't remotely work (no config parameter being set)

Do I need to serialize the object myself and set a `config` property or is there some other approach?

Comment: Let's take a step back. Why do you want to do that? What's the use case you are trying to solve?

Comment: For one thing, passing in the URL of the logo. If I hard code it in the customized page, I need to track that, should I change the location or name of the logo in the future, as opposed to just passing it in as a configuration parameter. In addition, configuration lets me pass in strings to be included in the login page - that's a pretty standard use case for any kind of templated page.

Comment: Wait... is `@@config@@` coming from somewhere else? I can't see anything in the `auth0-js` code that is setting up the properties that are then used in the hosted page...

Comment: https://auth0.com/docs/hosted-pages/login#pass-in-custom-parameters

Comment: Cool... so that's custom parameters, but what about something like `config.dict.signin.title` or `config.theme`? These are standard in the Hosted Login Page, but I cannot see where I would set those values

Comment: you would have to pass through querystring and modify the login page to take those things in the script

`config.dict.signing.title = config.extraParams.title`

Comment: If you want to do something more sophisticated you can send all that in base64 and (e.g. &config=base64ofJSONconfig) and decode it on the login page

Comment: note that by doing this the client is now in charge of changing the whole config object, which might open your code to vulnerabilities. e.g. you don't want to allow override certain parameters. That's why it has to be controlled by you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148429/discussion-between-dancrumb-and-woloski).

Answer (score 9):

I solved the mistery: you have to pass the parameters in the authorize call when you invoke the hosted login page. I made an example that allows to specify the hosted page's language with a parameter.

Script code:

```
var params=new Array();
params['language'] = 'es';

var webAuth = new auth0.WebAuth({
    domain: 'example.auth0.com',
    clientID: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
    redirectUri: 'https://www.example.com/redirect',
    audience: 'https://example.auth0.com/userinfo',
    responseType: 'code',
    scope: 'openid profile email',
    allowShowPassword: true,
});

webAuth.authorize(params);
```

Hosted page code:

```
var config = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(escape(window.atob('@@config@@'))));
var language;
if (config.extraParams.language)
  language = config.extraParams.language;
else
    language = 'en';

var lock = new Auth0Lock(config.clientID, config.auth0Domain, {
  ...
  language: language
});

lock.show();
```

So, any parameter you specify in the authorize call is accesible using the config.extraParams variable

P.D.: Months late, but I hope it help other users

Comment: Thanks. L1 in on the lock example is applicable for the webauth scenario as well. Where did you find about the @@config@@ placeholder? I googled and even searched on auth0 documentation, yet I couldn't find anything other than your answer.